# Font that is similar to the Hornsey Road Bath and Laundry painting in London?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

Any suggestions for a font that is similar to the one in the image below?

[image: Hornsey Road Baths & Laundry Image]

Comment: Have you tried identifying the font with [the stock tools](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366)?

Comment: Given that text in neon signs has round end caps, I'd say [Arial Rounded](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhnzwp2wdyift74/Myfonts%20-%20Arial-rounded.png?raw=1) is slightly closer, although not an exact match. It's pretty much just the `A` and `S` that are different, when compared to the letters in the example picture.

Comment: @Joonas And R, D, and O as well.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Marginally, I'd say. Compared side to side, sure but otherwise they are close enough as far as I'm concerned. That all depends on why the OP needs this font, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the real thing...

[image: Hornsey Road Baths]

You can see that all the terminals are straight and not rounded, and the R in particular has a soft angle for its sloping leg. That and the overall proportions indicate that the font is **Gill Sans Bold,** which was popular for this sort of thing in the 1950s.

[image]

[Main image](http://www.pbase.com/image/4525542) from [Paul and Jane](http://www.pbase.com/paulandjane/profile) via PBase.
Font image from [MyFonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/gill-sans/bold/)

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously hand-made, but [Granby](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ef/granby/) is quite similar in looking like a slightly more condensed version of Gill Sans with a straight leg.